# "glGenTextures" returns 1282 error when using 4.2 OpenGL

Tags: c, linux, opengl, freeglut

I'm creating OpenGL texture using default function *glGenTextures*. When OpenGL version set to 3.0 everything works fine, but when I override it with 4.2 *glGenTextures* starts to throw error #1282 (invalid operation). What i'm doing wrong?

Here's code segment I've tested:

```cpp
#include "GL/freeglut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"

#define MAJOR_GL_VERSION 3
#define MINOR_GL_VERSION 0

int w = 200;
int h = 200;
const char* title = "title";

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    puts("Overriding default OpenGL version...");

    glutInitContextVersion(MAJOR_GL_VERSION, MINOR_GL_VERSION);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA);
    glutInitWindowSize(w, h);
    glutCreateWindow(title);

    printf("Using OpenGL Version: %s\n=========\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST );
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );

    GLenum error;
    GLuint id = 0;

    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    if((error = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR || id == 0)
    {
        printf("Gl error: %s (errno %i)\n", gluErrorString(error), error);
        return 0;
    }

    while (1) { }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error does probably not happen in the line you expect it to happen. Chances are high that some of the methods before `glGenTextures` is the problem. Neither of this lines

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

are allowed in a OpenGL Core Profile. Profiles were introduces in OpenGL 3.2, thus the Core Profile request does not have any effect when requesting a 3.0 context. But with 3.2+, you'll get a core profile which removed a lot of stuff.

You can either remove the lines mentioned above and replace them with a Core-Profile compatible code. Or you could explicitly request a compatibility profile (`glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE)` when you want to stick to the fixed function pipeline.